# Payout to unregistered user with API REST

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I use the Paypal REST API to do single payout (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payouts). As receiver, I give an email address. All works as expected if I give an email corresponding to an existing Paypal sandbox account.

When I give an email that is not registered among my testing sandbox accounts, I would have expected than the receiver targeted by the payout would receive an email and be invited to create his Paypal account to claim his payout.

However, I got a `"RECEIVER_UNREGISTERED: Receiver is unregistered (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#RECEIVER_UNREGISTERED)."`

To give an email as receiver linked to an existing Paypal is it really mandatory ? If yes, what is your app workflow to send a Paypal Payout to unregistered Paypal users ?

Thanks !

Comment: did u got the solution for this error ?

Answer (score 1):

When you do a payout to an non-registered email, the status of the payout become "`Unclaimed`".

If the user is registered on PayPal, you will normally get a "`Success`" transaction status.

The error messages only have an informative purpose :

```
"errors":{
"name":"RECEIVER_UNREGISTERED",
"message":"Receiver is unregistered",
"information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/#errors",
"details":{}
},
```

The Sandbox is an isolated environnement and emails from the sandbox environnement are not sent to the end-users. That's why your payout receiver are not receiving any email asking to create a Paypal account. Same scenario if you send money to a phone number instead of an email address.

Receivers have 30 days to claim their money. After 30 days, the money is refunded to the payee.

You can read more about the status on the [Payout API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch#definition-transaction_enum).